# Buildout/Mr. Developer randomly failing to pull from Git

Tags: python, django, git, github, buildout

I'm using [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org) and [Mr.Developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) in order to set up my environment (both for development and deployments). Part of this set up is pulling a private git repository that is required for this project. (This is why I'm using Mr.Developer.)

Most of the time when I run buildout, everything is fine.

However, after outputting the line below, it will occasionally stop. It doesn't time out or anything, but it hangs here indefinitely:

```
mr.developer: Queued 'django-myotherproject' for checkout.
```

On a normal/successful buildout, it would have outputted:

```
mr.developer: Queued 'django-myotherproject' for checkout.
mr.developer: Cloned 'django-myotherproject' with git.
Develop: '/projects/myproject/develop/django-myotherproject'
```

**My initial thoughts:**

I assumed that it was my git repository host that was possibly timing out. However, I just switched to github, and I'm still experiencing this issue.

Since this only occurs randomly, I don't think it's an issue of the settings I've specified in my buildout configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of mr.developer are you using? [Version 1.20](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer/1.20#changelog), released 3 weeks ago (late February 2012) includes a refactoring of the thread-lock handling.

From the [original pull request](https://github.com/fschulze/mr.developer/pull/76) that lead to the refactor:

> lately, I noticed a very strange behavior in which, when using mr.developer, the buildout would sometimes hang on forever and never complete, right when it was checking out packages.

That sounds like exactly the kind of problems you are seeing.

Edit: [Version 1.21](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer/1.21#changelog) is now out and adds thread-control to the configuration. You can now create a `~/.buildout/mr.developer.cfg` file that sets the number of threads to 1 to avoid this problem altogether:

```
[mr.developer]
threads = 1
```

The default is 5.

Comment: I'm using version 1.20, but unfortunately, I'm still having this issue.

Comment: It looks like the upcoming 1.21 will address this by letting you tune the number of threads used, see commit [2e1fb58](https://github.com/fschulze/mr.developer/commit/2e1fb587814805779903c34f54e3421dd746f74b). Florian has yet to release 1.21 though, so some patience is required.

Comment: Version 1.21 has now been released; I've edited the answer to include a section on the new threads option.